# How can I transpose sections of a variable in Stata?

Tags: stata

I've seen some other examples of transposing columns and rows in Stata, but my problem is always a little different. What I want to do is sort entries and build several new columns based on one variable that is row-indexed. I have a "year" variable and a "data" variable, and I want to build new columns labeled by year and filled with corresponding numbers from "data" horizontally for each entry (ID).

[image: Current Data Format]
[image: Goal Format]

Comment: Your question is clear, but images are awkward to read and difficult to copy. Please see the Stata tag wiki on how to give a data example, or go straight to `help dataex` in Stata. (If you are using an old version of Stata, you will need to install it first using `ssc install dataex`.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data example is already in what Stata calls a "long" layout (some people say format or structure), which is best for most Stata purposes. What you want is a wide layout, which comes from a standard `reshape wide`, as follows:

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str1 ID float(Year XData)
"A" 2014  0
"A" 2015  7
"B" 2014 21
"B" 2015  0
"C" 2014  1
"C" 2015 18
"D" 2014 37
"D" 2015 20
"E" 2014  1
"E" 2015  3
end

. list, sepby(ID)

     +-------------------+
     | ID   Year   XData |
     |-------------------|
  1. |  A   2014       0 |
  2. |  A   2015       7 |
     |-------------------|
  3. |  B   2014      21 |
  4. |  B   2015       0 |
     |-------------------|
  5. |  C   2014       1 |
  6. |  C   2015      18 |
     |-------------------|
  7. |  D   2014      37 |
  8. |  D   2015      20 |
     |-------------------|
  9. |  E   2014       1 |
 10. |  E   2015       3 |
     +-------------------+

. reshape wide XData, i(ID) j(Year)
(note: j = 2014 2015)

Data                               long   ->   wide
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Number of obs.                       10   ->       5
Number of variables                   3   ->       3
j variable (2 values)              Year   ->   (dropped)
xij variables:
                                  XData   ->   XData2014 XData2015
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------


. rename XData* X*

. list

     +--------------------+
     | ID   X2014   X2015 |
     |--------------------|
  1. |  A       0       7 |
  2. |  B      21       0 |
  3. |  C       1      18 |
  4. |  D      37      20 |
  5. |  E       1       3 |
     +--------------------+
```

As above, you can `rename` your new variables, but the new names must start with a letter or an underscore. Bare numbers can't be variable names.